# Dictionnary that returns a list of a key entered in argument in a function

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Here is a sample of my dictionnary with 3 Keys.

```
({'Musique': [['Musique', 'Shawn Phillips', 236, 236], ['Musique', "L'avenue Royale fête l'été!", 237, 237], ['Musique', 'Perséides musicales', 215, 215], ['Musique', 'Gaétan Leclerc chante Félix et…', 229, 229], ['Musique', 'The Ring of Fire : a Johnny Cash Experience', 202, 202], ['Musique', "Jazz'Art", 208, 210],  {'Théatre': [['Théâtre', 'Coup de théâtre à la joyeuse maison hantée', 189, 189], ['Théâtre', 'Les galoches du bonheur', 203, 203], ['Théâtre', 'Le voyage de Pixelle dans le monde virtuel', 217, 217], ['Théâtre', 'Marimba à la ferme de la bonne entente', 224, 224], ['Théâtre', 'Pattes et cravates', 196, 196], {'Danse': [['Danse', 'Initiation au tango argentin suivi de la milonga', 182, 231], ['Danse', 'Samedi de danser...', 188, 188], ['Danse', 'Rusdell Nunez (latino)', 191, 191]
```

Keys are : `'Musique','Théâtre' and 'Danse`

This is a list of sublists of events and all the int in my dictionnary are when those events are available. I need to return a list with the name of all the events with the right type who are offered at the date entereted in argument `day_year`.

Here is the full instructions and the function:

```
def obtain_events_date_type(dictio_events_par_type, day_year, type_event): #first argument in the dictionnary so dont rly worry about it.
```

Then, for each event of the right type as the argument `type_event`, if the beginning of the event(which is the first int in the dictionnary is lower or even than the int and if the end of the event(the last in of every index you could say) is higher or even than the argument `day_year`, we can add the name of this event in the list of event since its available on this day. i need to return that list of events.

So if i entered

```
def obtain_events_date_type(creer_dictio, 236, 'Musique'):    
     #creer_dictio is my dictio in another function
```

I would need to add all events that are available on the day 236, for exemple the first values in my dictionnary mentionned in this post. Its possible there is more than 1 events on the same day. If there is no event available on the day enterered in argument we return an empty list.

What have i tried :

Im actually familiar with loops and stuff in python, but i keep getting code error about tuples and a bunch of operation not allowed on dictionnary.

Someone told me that i could create a list for every type, but im still having a time reaching every events and int asked in arguments.

Thanks for the info/tips !

**EDIT :**

```
liste_type_asked = []
for element in dictio_evenements_par_type:
    if 'Musique' in element:
        for jour in element:
            if jour_annee <= jour[2]:
                if jour_annee >= jour[3]:
                    liste_type_asked.append(element)    
return liste_type_asked
```

Error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Can you include what you've actually tried including errors? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @n8sty edited, i also get TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Obviously, one of the `jour_annee` and `jour[2]` is a string and the other is a number, and you cannot compare strings to numbers. Find out which one is which, and convert the string to a number.

Comment: @DYZ all right, but i need to know how i can reach an index of a dictionnary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
def obtain_events_date_type(dictio_events_par_type, day_year, type_event):
    return [n for t in dictio_events_par_type for k, l in t.items() if k == type_event for _, n, s, e in l if s <= day_year <= e]
```

so that:

```
events = [
    {
        'Musique': [
            ['Musique', 'Shawn Phillips', 236, 236],
            ['Musique', "L'avenue Royale fête l'été!", 237, 237],
            ['Musique', 'Perséides musicales', 215, 215],
            ['Musique', 'Gaétan Leclerc chante Félix et…', 229, 229],
            ['Musique', 'The Ring of Fire : a Johnny Cash Experience', 202, 202],
            ['Musique', "Jazz'Art", 208, 210]
        ]
    },
    {
        'Théâtre': [
            ['Théâtre', 'Coup de théâtre à la joyeuse maison hantée', 189, 189],
            ['Théâtre', 'Les galoches du bonheur', 203, 203],
            ['Théâtre', 'Le voyage de Pixelle dans le monde virtuel', 217, 217],
            ['Théâtre', 'Marimba à la ferme de la bonne entente', 224, 224],
            ['Théâtre', 'Pattes et cravates', 196, 196]
        ]
    },
    {
        'Danse': [
            ['Danse', 'Initiation au tango argentin suivi de la milonga', 182, 231],
            ['Danse', 'Samedi de danser...', 188, 188],
            ['Danse', 'Rusdell Nunez (latino)', 191, 191]
        ]
    }
]
print(obtain_events_date_type(events, 188, 'Danse'))
```

will output:

```
['Initiation au tango argentin suivi de la milonga', 'Samedi de danser...']
```

Comment: thanks, this might be it i will let you know if i need anything else or if i have any questions about the return just so i understand, thanks !